# Using arrays in making visitor log in management system

Tags: java, arrays, authentication, java.util.scanner

as you can clearly guess from the title I'm all new to programming and I don't have a clue on where to start. I was tasked to make a campus visitor log in management system with temporary data storage and limited number of people. I'm a freshman and we still haven't discussed SQL yet because it's only for sophomores. And my teacher suggested to use arrays since I'm still a beginner. Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated. So far this is what I have come up with so far,

```
        System.out.print("Enter number of visitors: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        //visitor's Information
        String name[] = new String[number];
        String department[] = new String[number];
        String reason[] = new String[number];

        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i<name.length;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
            name[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("\nEnter department: ");
            department[i]= input.next();
            System.out.print("\nEnter reason: ");
            reason[i]= input.next();
        }
        System.out.println();


        for(int i = 0; i<name.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Name: "+name);
            System.out.println("Department: " +department);
            System.out.println("Reason: "+reason);
        }


        //visitor's id number
        for(int i = 0; i<reason.length; i++)    {
            System.out.println(name[i]);
        }
}
```

}

And for some reason the results shows the addresses instead of the name, department, and reason. I'm at loss right now

Answer (score 1):

Within the for-loop you are not accessing the indexes of the arrays. You are currently printing the toString method of the String class (reference type of your arrays) by printing the object to the console without providing an index.

Change

```
for(int i = 0; i<name.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Name: "+name);
        System.out.println("Department: " +department);
        System.out.println("Reason: "+reason);
    }
```

To

```
for(int i = 0; i<name.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Name: "+name[i]);
        System.out.println("Department: " +department[i]);
        System.out.println("Reason: "+reason[i]);
    }
```

To further improve your code, you can try to create a few more methods that all do one thing. For example printing out the results containing the name, department and reason. This functionality could be moved to a method named printResults.

When you have got more experience programming, try to grab a book named Clean Code which is written by Robert C. Martin. Using the best practices mentioned in his book will help you create better and reusable code. I personally find this to be a must-read for every professional developer.